# Copying EXIF from One image to another using EXIF Tool Taking too long

Tags: c#, winforms, exif, exiftool

I'm using the following code to copy the exif data from one file to another using [exiftool](https://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/).

When directly run from command line,the tool is quick.But when the command is executed from a winform app,it takes much greater time.What is going wrong here? Please advice. Is there any alternative way to achieve this?

```
foreach(string cpath in filelist)
{
    string path = "-overwrite_original -TagsFromFile " + "\"" + file + "\"" +" "+ "\"" + outdir + "\\" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file) + ext + "\"";
                        runCmd(path);
}

  public void runCmd(string command)
    {

        ProcessStartInfo cmdsi = new ProcessStartInfo("exiftool.exe");
        cmdsi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        cmdsi.Arguments = command;
        Process cmd = Process.Start(cmdsi);
        cmd.WaitForExit();    
    }
```

Comment: And how big is filelist? Is it slow from the first file or becomes slower over time? How slow (1 second, 10)?

Comment: @Evk The result is the same irrespective of the list size.I have tried with a single file.The file is high resolution 6000×4000 pixels.Directly the process completes in 1 second ,from winforms it takes ~3 seconds

Comment: If you are running this on multiple files, one problem is covered by [Common Mistake #3](https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/mistakes.html#M3).  The startup time for exiftool is the biggest time cost, so running exiftool separately for each file will dramatically increase the overall run time.  Consolidating the file list into a single command or saving the list to a temp file and using the [`-@` option](https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/exiftool_pod.html#ARGFILE) will decrease the run time.

Comment: @StarGeek Thanks for your input,the startup time seems to be the culprit.I can write the list to a file,but how can i pass the output argument? Can you please add an example...

Comment: Continuing on your [exiftool forum thread](http://u88.n24.queensu.ca/exiftool/forum/index.php/topic,9121.0.html), as that is better suited to posting examples than commenting here.

Comment: @StarGeek Thanks :),i will follow-up there..